# closure library 2029 jar for use with Clojurescript

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, clojurescript

I've been unable to find a .jar for the new google-closure-library for use with [clojurescript](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/google-closure-library).

(source code downloads are available here: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/downloads/list)

I've also tried (unsuccessfully) compiling it through closurebuilder. (I've tried compiling it with the deps.js as recommended but that is not working either).

If anyone can point me to the 2029 jar or teach me how to compile it from source that would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, I do *not* mean the the closure compiler
I mean a .jar such as found here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/google-closure-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily jar the closure library to any version of your choice.

Just read up on how to jar a dir from the java docs found elsewhere. When you are done with that, you then use

```
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId="foo" -DproductId="bar" -Dversion="baz" -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="the jarred file"
```

to install it to your local .m2 repo. Lein should then be able to pull it in as needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think their may be some confusion here. The [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) is a set of JavaScript source files. You can compile them with the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), but they would still only produce a JavaScript file.

The [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is distributed as a jar file. It can also be downloaded as source code and compiled manually into a jar. It is used to compile JavaScript files into "better" JavaScript.

Comment: When working with clojurescript the closure library is distributed as a .jar - you then include it in the lein requirements like so:
[org.clojure/google-closure-library "0.0-1376"] - which includes this jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/google-closure-library

Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: Examining the JAR file looks to be just the raw source files of closure-library. You can create your own JAR file by setting up the folder structure, zipping the whole thing, and renaming the ZIP with a .JAR extension. Rename and unzip the current JAR file for guidance on setting up the folders.

Answer (score 1):

The Closure Library isn't released very often but you can grap the latest from SVN (or something near the release of the Compiler you are using if you aren't using the latest) it is designed to be "always good" (which is why it isn't released very often).